# Calculus - Related Rates : Shadow Problem

Tags: calculus, related-rates

Question state is : "A person 6 ft tall walks at 5 ft/s along one edge of a road 30 ft wide. On the other edge of the road is a light atop a pole 18 ft high. How fast is the length of the person’s shadow (on the horizontal ground) increasing when the person is 40 ft from the point directly across the road from the pole?"

However,

Comment: I think your work is pretty much correct, but remember it wants the rate of change of the length of the shadow, so $\frac{ds}{dt}$ not $\frac{dl}{dt}$. So since $s = \frac{1}{3}l$, your numbers match up.